# Setting up JPDA for Tomcat7 in ubuntu-server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7

I am attempting to setup the JPDA for Tomcat7 in ubuntu.
I have used the apt-get method of installing Tomcat7.
By attempting to edit the /usr/share/tomcat7/startup.sh file with the following lines I try to get tomcat7 to boot into debug mode and allow remote debugging via eclipse.

```
 JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
 JPDA_ADDRESS="8000"
 exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" jpda start "$@"
```

After editing the startup.sh file, I reboot tomcat7 using:

```
 sudo service tomcat7 restart
```

Then attempt to connect to the tomcat jpda in eclipse with the IP address and port 8000. I receive a "Connection Refused" error from Eclipse.

I have attempted to manually start tomcat7 using the startup.sh script rather than the service executable method as I thought perhaps the startup.sh was not being called.

```
sudo ./startup.sh
```

This failed with the following output:

```
 Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat7
 Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat7
 Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
 Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
 Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
 touch: cannot touch `/usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out': No such file or directory
 ./catalina.sh: 389: ./catalina.sh: cannot create /usr/share/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out: Directory nonexistent
```

I have also attempted to alter the startup script at /etc/init.d/tomcat7 as I am using service to start/restart tomcat7 to no avail...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Ubuntu 12.04+ there is a section like this in `/etc/default/tomcat7`:

```
# To enable remote debugging uncomment the following line.
# You will then be able to use a java debugger on port 8000.
#JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

So just uncomment it and run `sudo service tomcat7 restart`.

Comment: Thank you very much, the websites I visited seemed to complicate the procedure.

Comment: Note:  The debugger won't stop at your breakpoints unless you change `suspend=n` to `suspend=y`.

Comment: @SteelNation It will also stop at breakpoints with `suspend=n`, as long as a debugger is attached. With `suspend=y`, the JVM will wait until a debugger is attached to begin execution, while with `n` it will start execution right away and let you attach a debugger afterward. The `y` option is mostly useful when you want to debug the startup process itself. To debug regular servlets, I find it more convenient to use `suspend=n` and connect to the running instance when I need to.

Comment: Huh... it definitely was not stopping breakpoints from catching for me. I wonder what the difference is in our setups... I'm debugging a pretty standard Java EE servlet on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Aw. You were right... turned out I have to manually delete the old .war file before rebuilding. After doing that, I can catch break points with `suspend=n`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Settings required in Tomcat:

1)Create setenv.sh file under */tomcat/bin/. The location will be same as the catalina.sh file

2)Place the below content inside it.

export CATALINA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
Now start the Tomcat server. Once it is started please proceed with the below steps.

Settings required in Eclipse:

3)In Eclipse go to Windows-->Preference--> General-->Network Connection --> Active Provider should be Direct. After changing to direct restart the eclipse.

4)In eclipse right click on project and debug as ->debug configuration ->Remote java application ->Create new configuration.

Fill the below fields

Name: as your wish

Project: Select the project which you need to debug.

ConnectionType: Standard socket attach

Host: Localhost Port: 8000(It should be same as mentioned in point 2)

Then click debug.

The debug will start at port 8000. Now you can verify by keeping breakpoints.