# Tomcat 7 server says it's listening on debug port but doesn't accept any connections

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7, remote-debugging

I'm working with a Tomcat 7 server running on Ubuntu. I've configured the etc/default/tomcat7 file to accept remote debugging requests through the instruction in this thread: [Setting up JPDA for Tomcat7 in ubuntu-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19578851/setting-up-jpda-for-tomcat7-in-ubuntu-server)

When the server restarts, in the catalina log file, it says that it's listening on port 8000, but I can't connect to it.

```
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
```

I've tried connecting to it through Window's Telnet tool as well as through the Eclipse debugger but the connection is always rejected. I also had all 4 of my teammates try connecting to it as well, to rule out issues with my own firewall, but they were unsuccessful as well.

These are the settings for my Eclipse debugger:

[image]

And the error message in Eclipse:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to connect from the server? Like `telnet localhost 8000`

Comment: Yep, that was actually the test that I had my teammates run to see if my firewall was blocking the connection. It failed for all four of us.

Comment: Wouldn't all of them failing *confirm* that it's a firewall problem?

Comment: I was assuming that it could be my firewall own computer's firewall settings. Do you mean that the server could be rejecting certain requests and not others? I'm not sure how I would check for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more digging, it turns out that AWS was blocking the port.

For anyone reading this, you can check to see if the port is being blocked through: [yougetsingal's port forward checking tool](https://www.yougetsignal.com/).